# switch to WebView by executing driver.context() with appium

Tags: android, selenium-chromedriver, android-webview, appium

**Problem**

I use appium for android automation on real device. I switch to WebView use driver.context("webview_com.xxx.myapp"), Then I execute driver.getPageSource(),and a question appear,it returned as follows

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body><iframe name="chromedriver dummy frame" src="about:blank"></iframe></body></html>`

**Environment**

```
appium:1.15.1
OS:Windows 10
API :java
Android:8.1
```

**Details**

My DesiredCapabilities as follows

```
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "b307aa10");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "appium");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.dayizhihui.dayishi.hpv");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".main.view.WelcomeActivity");
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromeOptions.put("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,chromeOptions);
```

My code as follows

```
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        introducePageHandle.clickIntroduceIcon();
        System.out.println("Before " + driver.getContext());
        System.out.println("All Contexts " + driver.getContextHandles());
        driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.dayizhihui.dayishi.hpv");
        System.out.println("After " + driver.getContext());
        System.out.println("PageSource " + driver.getPageSource());
```

The excute Result

```
Before NATIVE_APP
All Contexts [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_com.dayizhihui.dayishi.hpv, WEBVIEW_chrome]
After WEBVIEW_com.dayizhihui.dayishi.hpv
PageSource <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body><iframe name="chromedriver dummy frame" src="about:blank"></iframe></body></html>
```

I really want to someone can help me to solve it,thanks advanced!

[chrome inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9L6U.png)

[the app h5 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8Ldq.png)

Answer (score 0):

After switching to the webview, you need to switch to the `iframe` as an iframe is present on the webview on which you are trying to interact with.
You can switch to the iframe like:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("chromedriver dummy frame")));
```

Comment: The html you have mentioned in the question is of an iframe, and did you try the code i have mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion, but returned **no such element**. In fact, this frame should not exist

Comment: thanks,the html is not a iframe,Please check the photos I just uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Set the capability with `autoWebview`:

```
capabilities.setCapability("autoWebview", true);
```

[Docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me. I see a line of code in the appium server log, like this. Maybe that's reason    `Responding to client with driver.setContext() result: null`